# Trying to write a List object to XML (VB.net)

Tags: xml, vb.net, list

I've had no trouble writing a non-List object to XML, it reads and writes as expected. But making a List object write to XML is throwing my entire export/import process against the wall, and I can't figure out why.

Object is built off of this class:

```
    Public Class PowerArray
    'Array that stores Powers for active character
    Public Name As String
    Public PRating As Integer
    Public Action As String
    Public Cost As Integer
    Public PoolNone As String
    Public Pool1 As String
    Public Pool2 As String
    Public Range As String
    Public Duration As String
    Public Tags As New List(Of Object)
    Public Desc As String
End Class
```

Object created from the Class is:

```
Public Shared Property CharPowers As New List(Of PowerArray)
```

As an example, I can write the Object "CharCore" (as defined off of class "Character", and which isn't a list) to XML just fine.

If I try to write CharPowers as a populated List to XML, it throws an error from this:

```
    Dim writer As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(frmMain.PowerArray))
    Dim file As New System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\temp\" + "PowerTest.PWR")
    writer.Serialize(file, frmMain.GVar.CharPowers)
    file.Close()
```

-with error "InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[NICO_SP_v2.frmMain+PowerArray]' to type 'PowerArray'."

I'm not sure what makes a List different here. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: adding notes, re: Character class

```
Dim writer As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(Character))
    Dim file As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\temp\chartest_A.STC")
    writer.Serialize(file, GVar.CharacterFile)
```

Comment: Show the Xml. I'm sure there's a root element. Xml must have a root element, so you will need some element enclosing the list. Maybe whatever GVar is?

Comment: GVar is a Public Class that holds declarations (like "Public Shared Property CharPowers As New List(Of PowerArray)").

Not sure what you mean by "show the XML"? There isn't any, the process attempting to write it errors out before there's any output to file, "PowerTest.PWR" is blank.

Comment: I can safely say doing a For loop isn't the plan. Every new entry appends "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>" to it.

Comment: Well if you don't have desired Xml then I can make some up for you :)

Comment: You could probably put all your data into the same Xml file and periodically or on demand read and write to it. Build upon my solution to create a master root class with many properties in it ranging from single elements to lists like you struggle with above. Would be cleaner than writing multiple files but of course depends on your app.

Comment: Honestly I'm struggling to do exactly that, but building a master root class with properties from various classes (like PowerArray - some lists, some not) is exactly what I was going for. Tried a few different methods, but admittedly I'm not the most savvy with XML formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[An Xml document must have a root element](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp), i.e. cannot just have a bunch of elements at the top level. So instead make a class to hold the list of PowerArray

Make your classes like this

```vb
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
```

```vb
<XmlRoot>
Public Class PowerArrays
    <XmlElement("PowerArray")>
    Public Property List As List(Of PowerArray)
End Class

Public Class PowerArray ' unchanged
    'Array that stores Powers for active character
    Public Name As String
    Public PRating As Integer
    Public Action As String
    Public Cost As Integer
    Public PoolNone As String
    Public Pool1 As String
    Public Pool2 As String
    Public Range As String
    Public Duration As String
    Public Tags As New List(Of Object)
    Public Desc As String
End Class
```

And serialize the root instead

```vb
Dim powers = New PowerArrays() With {.List = frmMain.GVar.CharPowers.ToList()}
Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(PowerArrays))
Using writer As New StreamWriter($"c:\temp\{PowerTest.PWR}")
    serializer.Serialize(writer, powers)
End Using
```

Your Xml should result in

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PowerArrays>
  <PowerArray>
    <Name>foo</Name>
    ...
  </PowerArray>
  <PowerArray>
    <Name>bar</Name>
    ...
  </PowerArray>
</PowerArrays>
```

Deserialize in reverse

```vb
Dim powers = New PowerArrays()
Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(PowerArrays))
Using reader As New StreamReader($"c:\temp\{PowerTest.PWR}")
    powers = DirectCast(serializer.Deserialize(reader), PowerArrays)
End Using
```

Comment: Oh wait NOW I see what you were saying, with regard to XML structure! Sorry about that, I misunderstood the initial question. This makes a lot more sense than what I was trying!

Comment: Ultimately, the final savefile XML's root structure would likely just be "Character", with things like "PowerArrays" nested inside of it.

This makes doing that a lot clearer - if I'm understanding right, doing that would require declaring "Character" (in this case) as a class, and XMLElements naming each section (PowerArray, X, Y, Z etc) in that same Class?

Comment: Hm...no, seems that doesn't work. I can't for the life of me figure out how to nest things in a class that can be referenced for XML output later on.

Comment: @ecit I like to go code first, so build your classes inside one master class, Character, maybe (if there is only one character) and put all the properties in there which can be other classes or lists of classes or primitives. Then serialize the Character class to Xml and see if it looks right. Deserialization would again just be the reverse as I show above.

Comment: @ecit btw does Tags need to be a `List(Of Object)`? Object doesn't serialize to Xml well.

Comment: It could be a List(Of String) and still accomplish the same goal, think I forgot to change that one off. Will update that, good catch.

It hadn't occurred to me to just create a Class and nest all of the various classes here inside it that way, hm. That would allow just using a generalized serialize operation, no?

Comment: @ecit you still need to specifically create the serializer using the type of your root class, but maybe you meant general in a different sense

Comment: That is what I meant, yes. Apologies for word choice there. So, I condensed all of those myriad classes ("Power" and the like) under one root public class, Character. Then made an object (I think) in gvar, "Public Shared Property Character CharacterFile as New Character" (so like CorePowers before, it's gvar.CharacterFile). Edited OP to include how I tried to write it out at the end, but the method I'm using doesn't seem to serialize, or even read, the object's values. It outputs an XML file with a header, but no data.

Comment: @ecit the right thing to do is probably to make a new question including the structure of your classes and put that serialization code in there too, describe the new issue (even put a link to your question above) and I'll take a look as soon as you do

Comment: @ecit sorry, just realized you already did :)